# Best method to print using wpf 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Howdy,
I need to be able to print from my wpf application. I am just trying to print a transaction receipt.

I have found that using

```
PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
```

pDialog.PrintVisual(new Receipt("transaction name","my store"), "documentTitle");

Does the trick very nicely. "Receipt() is a usercontrol that renders out the transaction details.

How are you meant to do this? is this the correct way? what do I do if I dont know the printer that is going to be used? should I make the usercontrol only as wide as a thermal receipt printer?

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I do to print a WPF control:

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = 
       printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

    double scale = Math.Min(
                     capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / control.ActualWidth, 
                     capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / control.ActualHeight);

    control.LayoutTransform = new System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

    Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, 
                       capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

    control.Measure(sz);
    control.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, 
       capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

    printDlg.PrintVisual(control, "My App");
}
```

This seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the printer that is going to be used and want to ask the user, does that mean you want to show the print dialog? How about:

```
pDialog.ShowDialog();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.showdialog.aspx