# Is it possible to use PrintVisual on a window that hasn't called Show()

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I've been reading all over but I cannot seem to find any examples of printing a window using PrintVisual(...) without calling Show() on it. Is there anyone who can assist? If even to say that it cannot happen so I can look for alternative solution.

This thread: [Best method to print using wpf 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662765/best-method-to-print-using-wpf-4)
seems to be what a lot of people reference, but it still requires a call to Show().

```
<Window x:Class="Paymax.Printing.PrintPayAdvice"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Testing 123" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintVisual(wpfControl, "Sample Print");
```

It would print to default printer that it is assigned to. You want to setup the `PrintQueue` and `PrintTicket` for the `PrintDialog` class if you want to extend it without having to call the `Show` method.

Assuming you have access to your window and named it `contentVisual`.

```
contentVisual.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
contentVisual.Arrange(new Rect(contentVisual.DesiredSize));
contentVisual.UpdateLayout();
```

Then call `Print`

Comment: I tried that, but without first calling wpfWindow.Show(), the ActualHeight and ActualWidth are both 0.0 so a blank page gets printed.

Comment: Show me your control.

Comment: Tried it but contentVisual.DesiredSize = {0,0} so still nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Do you really not to not call Show()? Can you do a Show() but the Visibility is `Collapsed`?